# Will database be hit 2 times by this code?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, scrollableresults

I am trying to improve performance of an api. I need to know whether the second line that's marked will hit database too ? as I want to minimise that.

```
     StringBuffer queryBuf = new StringBuffer("some query in SQL");
--------->StringBuffer queryBuf2 = new StringBuffer(" SELECT DISTINCT PP.ID FROM ( " + queryBuf + ") PP ");
        Query query1 = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryBuf2.toString());
        query1.setReadOnly(true);
        ScrollableResults results = query1.scroll();
        if (results.isLast() == false)
            results.last();
        int total = results.getRowNumber() + 1;
        results.close();
        logger.debug(">>>>>>TOTAL COUNT<<<<<< = {}", total);
```

Comment: That line creates a string buffer, like the two above. None of those "hit the database".

Comment: Your code won't even compile.

Comment: You can use Integer count= ((Long)query1.uniqueResult()).intValue(); to get the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know whether the second line that's marked will hit database too ?

You are constructing `StringBuffer` objects in first three lines , why should it hit the DB ! You can use `StringBuilder` if synchronization is not required !

Comment: You are right but i didn't understand then how "total" gets evaluated and showing correct no of rows, when the "results" is dependent on "query1" and "query1" on "queryBuf2".

Answer (score 2):

No. Only the line `ScrollableResults results = query1.scroll();` executes sql.

Also, you may want to use [SQL COUNT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Its plain and simple it wont hit , you are just creating StringBuffer objects.

Answer (score 2):

you are just create a string buffer. its not hitting the db. If i right this code may give compile error.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not hit the database. It will query from the buffer created by first query.